# Problem with editor formatting when using Edge Broswer

Tags: bug, editor

I have recently noticed a couple of problems when using the editor to re-edit an answer when using the `Edge` browser on Windows 10:

1. the editor is scrolled to the bottom of the text (as oppose to starting at the top), when you click the "Edit" link.
2. I now see 3 blank lines are displayed for each blank line used for spacing in the original answer.

Using `Edge` the editor looks like this:

[image]

Using `Firefox` the editor looks like:

[image]

As you can see in the Edge browser the extra white space makes it hard to follow the flow of the answer. This is behaviour that I noticed only start to happen in the past week.

Does adding the "Bug" tag to this question mean someone from StackOverflow will look into it? Or is there some other place I should report this behaviour?

Comment: @Spevacus, thanks, I am using the same version of Edge as indicated in the other question. Looks like I may need a browser update, but it's still curious that like the other user I only noticed this problem in the past week. I'm not aware of any updates that have been done to my computers. I have two that use Edge. That is why I still question if anything has changed on SE? In any case I will close this question to keep all the information in a single question.